# Splitting one string row into multiple rows of 50 characters, without using cursors, and not in the middle of words

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to take this to the next level... How can I keep this from splitting on words.  I want it to only split on spaces?

**here is a sample of the string I'm trying to break into multiple rows.**

> SARASOTA MANATEE AIRPORT BEING THAT
>   PORTION OF LANDS LYING OUTSIDE OF
>   SARASOTA CITY LIMITS DESC IN ORI
>   2000036853, ENTIRE PARCEL BEING DESC
>   AS LYING IN SARASOTA COUNTY, CITY OF
>   SARASOTA & PORTION OF FORMER OLD
>   BRADENTON RD LYING NLY OF UNIVERSITY
>   PKWY & GEN SPAATZ BLVD, LESS LANDS
>   LYING ELY OF W R/W LINE OF SEABOARD
>   COAST LINE RR, LESS TRACT LEASED TO
>   SMITH AT NE COR OF US HWY 41 & LESS
>   PARKING AREA LEASED TO UNIV OF SO FLA
>   ON N SIDE OF GEN SPAATZ BLVD, LESS
>   LEASED PARCELS FOR HERTZ, AVIS,
>   NATIONAL, BUDGET, DOLLAR & ALAMO CAR
>   RENTALS, LESS TRACT MEASURING 100 FT
>   BY 110 FT LEASED TO AIRCRAFT SVCS INTR
>   INC, LESS RD R/W FOR UNIVERSITY PKWY &
>   US 301, CONTAINING 145 C-AC M/L, L & B
>   IN SEC 1-36-17 & SEC 6-36-18

I don't want to get

- SARASOTA MANATEE AIRPORT BEING THAT PORTION OF LAN
- DS LYING OUTSIDE OF SARASOTA CITY LIMITS DESC IN O
- etc....

**Here is my sql**

```
>     SELECT REPLACE(dl.ParcelID, '-', '') As strap,
>     x.number AS num, 
>     SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(dl.legaldescription)),((number-1)*50)+1,50)
> AS dscr
>     FROM
>     (SELECT dld.accountnumber, dp.parcelid, dld.legaldescription 
>       FROM t1..DataLegalDescription dld
>       JOIN t1..DataProperty dp ON dp.accountnumber = dld.accountnumber
> AND dp.cardnumber = 1
>       JOIN t1..ManatronRealSamples mrs ON mrs.parcelid = dp.parcelid) AS dl
>     CROSS APPLY (SELECT number FROM MASTER.dbo.spt_values
>     WHERE TYPE = 'p' AND number > 0
>     AND number <= (DATALENGTH(legaldescription)/50+1)) x
>     ORDER BY x.number
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER FUNCTION SPLIT(@VALUE NVARCHAR(MAX),@LEN INT)
RETURNS @TEMP TABLE (ORIG_STRING NVARCHAR(MAX),PARTIAL_STRING NVARCHAR(MAX),LINE_NUM INT)
as
BEGIN
DECLARE @TEMP_STRING NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TEMP_FULL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @LINE_NUM INT

SET @TEMP_FULL = @VALUE
SET @TEMP_STRING = dbo.RegexStrMatch(@TEMP_FULL,'^(.{0,'+ CAST(@LEN AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) +'}(?:\s))',1)
SET @LINE_NUM = 1

WHILE LEN(@TEMP_FULL) >= @LEN
     BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO @TEMP VALUES(@VALUE,@TEMP_STRING,@LINE_NUM)     
        SET @TEMP_FULL = SUBSTRING(@TEMP_FULL,LEN(@TEMP_STRING)+1,LEN(@TEMP_FULL))      
        SET @LINE_NUM = @LINE_NUM + 1
        SET @TEMP_STRING = dbo.RegexStrMatch(@TEMP_FULL,'^(.{0,'+ CAST(@LEN AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) +'}(?:\s))',1)            
     END
        INSERT INTO @TEMP VALUES(@VALUE,@TEMP_STRING,@LINE_NUM)
RETURN 
END
GO
```

Followed by a simple `CROSS APPLY`

```
select accountNumber,Partial_String,Line_num from ..datalegaldescription dl
CROSS APPLY SPLIT(dl.legaldescription,50)
```

Answer (score 2):

As much as I admire your willingness to tackle this with SQL... I believe (all things equal) that arithmetic and string manipulation is generally better (and more efficiently) handled in code than by database engines.

I realize there may be valid reasons why you need to make your database engine do this work... so perhaps my "answer" is a less-than-helpful observation.  Just thought it was an observation worth making.

Comment: this is a one time data conversion, and the script is already there.  I don't want/need to create yet *another* codebase to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with codemonkey, but, if you have to do it, the general approach is to try to grab the next 50 characters and check for a space.  If the 50th char is a space, great, you got your line.  If not, check char 49, 48, etc., until you find a space.  That's the end of your next line.

Assuming, of course, there aren't any words that exceed the length of the line...

HTH